# Freenx with ssh that requires keys?

Tags: ssh, keys, freenx

Is it possible to connect to a Freenx server if ssh requires the use of keys instead of passwords? If so, how would I connect using the client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look [documentation](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/FreeNX#head-3a2e4992e1d6b6365aa4205abd4ca269e3b81053).